# Добавим SASS/SCSS в сниппеты кода?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, сниппеты

Вопрос по вопросам по фронтэнду.

Проблема: иногда автору нужно добавить код, но он пользуется препроцессорами CSS. Тогда либо:

1. Автор кидает код, но без сниппета (так как препроцессоры у нас в сниппетах не поддерживаются).
2. Даёт ссылку на какой-нибудь сайт, который поддерживает эти сниппеты (например CodePen).
3. Либо и то, и другое, но сниппета по сути нет.

То есть проблема в том, что для отображения результата приходится в любом случае пользоваться третьесторонними сайтами.

Я добавил на главную мету [предложение добавления SASS и SCSS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297810/346987), но, видимо, оно вышло каким-то спорным (два голоса и два голоса против на момент написания ответа), так как некоторые считают, что добавление SCSS и SASS противоречит [созданию минимального, самодостаточного и воспроизводимого примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

А как вы считаете? Давайте всё оставим как есть? Нам действительно будет мешать, если внедрят эту возможность?

#### Важно!

Если вы всё-же хотите чтобы это внедрили, то проголосуйте за [это предложение](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297810/346987) на главной мете.

Comment: Stylus, CoffeeScript, Slim и прочие препроцессоры, что имеются на вышеупомянутом Codepen, также не помешали бы. Спасибо.

Comment: В кодупен есть, но и здесь не помещало.

Comment: Я в принципе за